# Add Button in TabContainer for header Template[Make Visible as OutSide TabContainer]

Tags: asp.net, .net, css

i Trying to display a Button Just above a Tab Container.Like this
[image: DemoTab]

To Achieve this i need to do like this.
Correct me when i am wrong.

There are two possible solution for this

1. Set the Absolute positioning for Button so i fit just above the Tab Container.
2. For Tab Container

   2. Add CSS for Header Template so it invisible,
   3. Calculate Width of Client Screen.
   4. Stretch the Header Width till First visible Tab
   5. Set Content Template Visible false.
   6. And Align Button to Left

but so far i am not succeeded in any of one.